# Lentidão na criação de PDF - DOMPDF Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pdf

Estou atualmente usando o [Barryvdh\DomPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) para criar relatórios em um sistema feito com `Laravel 5.1`, porém está muito lento por causa do tamanho dos relatórios, de forma que, por muitas vezes(quase sempre), acaba até esgotando o tempo limite de carregamento.

Eu faço todo o relatório como se fosse uma `view` normal e depois carrego ela em PDF, conforme a documentação, com o `loadView`. Os relatórios tem umas 70 páginas.

Como posso otimizar isso?

Comment: Eu uso o laravel-snappy, gostei muito dele. É fácil de usar e eu obtive um desempenho bem satisfatório.
 https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

Comment: Bem, há possibilidades de você poder rodar na linha de comando?

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada nesse snappy @FelipePaetzold

Comment: Desculpe mas não entendi, rodar o que @WallaceMaxters?

Comment: Linha de comando, rodar algum comando via terminal. Você usa servidor compartilhado ou dedicado?

Comment: A ta, é compartilhado